# Trouble with naming/generating form fields in Ruby/Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm somewhat new to Ruby/Rails, which I find involves a lot of "magic."  This can be a great thing, but it also makes it very hard to figure out why something works or (in this case) doesn't.  My problem is figuring out how to name/configure my form fields so that things "just work."

There are four primary objects that I'm working with, Datasets, Requirements, Modules, and Configurations (named datasets, module_requirements, mods, and module_configurations below).  Modules have Requirements (many-to-many), and there may be multiple Datasets that fulfill a particular Requirement (many-to-one).  A Module may have many Configurations (one-to-many).  Through these relationships, we can see that a Configuration may be associated with many Datasets (many-to-many).  The actual association between a particular Configuration and some particular Datasets is managed via a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.

I am creating an interface to allow users to edit a Configuation by selecting which Datasets will be used to fullfil the associated Module's Requirements.

So the user is on the Configuration page, and sees a list of drop-down boxes, one for each Requirement.  The drop-downs are each filled with the various Datasets that can fulfill a given Requirement.  My problem is that I cannot figure out how to structure the form fields so that the selected Datasets are saved when the form is submitted.

```
==> The basic data model in more detail:

class Dataset < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :module_requirement
    has_many :mods, :through => :module_requirement
    has_many :module_configurations, :through => :mods
end

class ModuleRequirement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dataset_type
  has_and_belongs_to_many :mod
  has_many :module_configuration, :through => :mod, :source => :module_configurations
  has_many :dataset
end

class Mod < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,        :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true,
                          :length => { :minimum => 5 }

  has_and_belongs_to_many :module_requirements  
  has_many :module_configurations
  has_many :datasets, :through => :module_requirements
end

class ModuleConfiguration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mod
  has_many :module_requirements, :through => :mod
  has_and_belongs_to_many :datasets
end
```

.

```
==> From module_configurations_controller.rb:

def edit
    @module_configuration = ModuleConfiguration.find(params[:id])

    # List datasets by their requirements to provide a drop down box for each requirement listing only relevant datasets
    @datasetsByReq = Hash.new

    Dataset.all.collect{ |d| if(!d.module_requirement.nil?)
                               @datasetsByReq[d.module_requirement.id] ||= Array.new   # Create an empty array if needed
                               @datasetsByReq[d.module_requirement.id].push(d)         # Append config to the array
                             end }   

    # Find the selected dataset for each requirement                             
    @selectedDataset = Hash.new
    @module_configuration.datasets.all.collect{ |d| @selectedDataset[d.module_requirement.id] = d}
end


def update
    @module_configuration = ModuleConfiguration.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @module_configuration.update_attributes(params[:module_configuration])
        format.html { redirect_to @module_configuration, notice: 'Module configuration was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @module_configuration.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

.

```
==> From module_configurations/edit.html.erb

<%= simple_form_for(@module_configuration) do |f| %>

  ... other fields here ...

  <!-- Produce one dropdown filled with datasets per requirement: -->
  <% config.mod.module_requirements.each do |req| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :datasets , req do |r|%>

      <% selected = @selectedDataset[req.id].nil? ? -1 : @selectedDataset[req.id].id%>              <== Problem is likely here...

      <%= collection_select :requirement_id, :dataset_id, @datasetsByReq[req.id] || [], :id, :name, <== ...and/or here
                         :include_blank => 'None specified', :selected => selected %> 
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When editing a module_configuration, the user should be able to select a dataset for each requirement.  The code above produces the dropdowns ok, but I cannot figure out what to name them such that the data will be saved when the form is submitted.

Using the latest release of everything, running on Linux.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

---

No longer looking for a solution, solved via a different mechanism.  I did confirm that the problem was related to the way the collection_select was named, but I'm afraid a full explanation would be so esoteric and specific that it would be useless to the community.

Comment: Could you make your question more succinct?

Comment: I was going for the "bloated question" badge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the logic of your different models cause there seems to be a lot of relationships between these classes that are hard for me to wrap my head around at the moment. But if your form is working correctly with your models using the relationships, then you should be alright.

If your just having problems getting the form to save, then your models need to know that they should save *nested* attributes or models with relationships to the current model. You do this with the following command in your model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :relationship_name
```

so for example, one class might like this:

```
class ModuleConfiguration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mod
  has_many :module_requirements, :through => :mod
  has_and_belongs_to_many :datasets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :datasets
end
```

This will add the necessary methods to your model to save the data from relationship models.  Another rule of thumb that I have is that you should never really use loops in your form when its over a relationship in the model that your working with. This is because `f.fields_for :relationship_name` will automatically loop over the relationships. In Rails whenever you feel like your working against the grain, it usually means there's an easier way to do it.